# Unexpected token; 'module, class, interface, enum, import or statement' expected. in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to learn typescript and angular.I write code

```
**main.ts**
import { LikeComponent } from "./like.component";

let component = new LikeComponent(10,true);
component.onClick();
console.log(`likescount: ${component.likesCount}, isSelect: ${component.isSelected}`);

**like.component.ts**
export class LikeComponent
{
    constructor(public likesCount: number,public isSelected: boolean) {

    }
    onClick() {
        this.likesCount += (this.isSelected) ? 1: -1;
        this.isSelected = !this.isSelected;
    }
}
```

but it throws error like
[image]

I have folder structure like,

[image]

I have tried adding below code in tsconfig.js but not luck

```
    {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried to run only 'tsc like.component.cs' but got an error like 'cannot run external module unless--module is provided'.

tsc --version : 1.0.3.0

Comment: Do you really require usage of Typescript 1 or can you upgrade to version 2 or even 3? Can you give us the content of tsconfig.json?

Comment: Your error is in `main.ts` but you are not showing it.

Comment: @StéphaneVeyret I will try with upgraded version of typescript.Also provided tsconfig.json. I was trying with different solution not sure what the main usage of that "Files" tag.

Comment: @Ebuall please check updated question

Comment: @Dhara I mean the full tsconfig.json. Especially, what do you have as `target`, `module`, `libs` in your `compilerOptions`? Files is used to specify files to be compiled as you can see here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: @StéphaneVeyret I have updated question

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade TypeScript.  I wasn't able to find your exact version 1.0.3.0, but I tried version 1.0.0.0 (on npm as 1.0.0), which is 4 years old, and I got the same errors.  TypeScript 3.0.3 compiles your code with no trouble.